# How to implement an infinite integer iterator?

Tags: rust, iterator

I have created an iterator to generate an infinite list of integers from 0 onwards as shown below.

```
struct Infinite {
    current: i64,
}

impl Infinite {
    fn new() -> Infinite {
        Infinite { current: -1 }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Infinite {
    type Item = i64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.current += 1;
        Some(self.current)
    }
}
```

I hope to manipulate this list of integers with different commands such as Multiply (to multiple each integer by a number n) or subtract (to subtract n from each integer). Thus, I created a Multiply struct and implemented an iterator for it as shown below.

```
struct Multiply {
    n: i64,
    inner: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i64>>,
}

impl Multiply {
    fn new(inner: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i64>>, n: i64) -> Multiply {
        Multiply { n, inner }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Multiply {
    type Item = i64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        Some(self.inner.next().unwrap() * self.n)
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure how to implement this in the main function. Should I begin by defining a new `iter` object this way?

```
let mut iter = Infinite::new();
    iter.next();
```

Then, how should I implement the Multiply iterator to `iter`?

Comment: It is not infinite, it will stop when overflowing (at least in debug mode).

Comment: Well if we are in nitpicking mode: assuming you can iterate with 10 GigaIterations/s, then `9_223_372_036_854_775_807 / 10_000_000_000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365 = 29.24 years` to overflow. Which is, in my eyes, fine to call 'infinite'. Unless you put it on a satelite or similar.

Comment: I've maybe misunderstood what you want to archive but you can get an infinite iterator with the range `0..`, and you can multiply the elements with `Iter::map`. if you want for example to multiply everything by 2 you could do `(0..).map(|x| x * 2)`. It feel like you are just reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut iter = Multiply::new(Box::new(Infinite::new()), 2);

    println!("{}", iter.next().unwrap());
    println!("{}", iter.next().unwrap());
    println!("{}", iter.next().unwrap());
}
```

```
0
2
4
```

---

That said, it's pretty unusual for an iterator to carry a `Box` object.
It's usually done with a generic. (Also, don't use `.unwrap()` when mapping from one iterator to another, use `Option::map()` instead to preserve the end of the iterator)

```rust
struct Infinite {
    current: i64,
}

impl Infinite {
    fn new() -> Infinite {
        Infinite { current: -1 }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Infinite {
    type Item = i64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.current += 1;
        Some(self.current)
    }
}

struct Multiply<I> {
    n: i64,
    inner: I,
}

impl<I> Multiply<I> {
    fn new(inner: I, n: i64) -> Multiply<I> {
        Multiply { n, inner }
    }
}

impl<I> Iterator for Multiply<I>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = i64>,
{
    type Item = i64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.inner.next().map(|n| n * self.n)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut iter = Multiply::new(Infinite::new(), 2);

    println!("{}", iter.next().unwrap());
    println!("{}", iter.next().unwrap());
    println!("{}", iter.next().unwrap());
}
```

```
0
2
4
```

---

Further, this is usually done with an extension trait for `Iterator` so you are able to chain it. This is also how the entire [`itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/) crate works.

```rust
struct Infinite {
    current: i64,
}

impl Infinite {
    fn new() -> Infinite {
        Infinite { current: -1 }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Infinite {
    type Item = i64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.current += 1;
        Some(self.current)
    }
}

struct Multiply<I>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = i64>,
{
    n: i64,
    inner: I,
}

impl<I> Iterator for Multiply<I>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = i64>,
{
    type Item = i64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.inner.next().map(|n| n * self.n)
    }
}

trait MultiplyExt
where
    Self: Iterator + Sized,
{
    fn multiply_with(self, n: i64) -> Multiply<Self>
    where
        Self: Iterator<Item = i64>,
    {
        Multiply { n, inner: self }
    }
}

impl<T: Iterator> MultiplyExt for T {}

fn main() {
    let mut iter = Infinite::new().multiply_with(2);

    println!("{}", iter.next().unwrap());
    println!("{}", iter.next().unwrap());
    println!("{}", iter.next().unwrap());
}
```

```
0
2
4
```

Comment: It is also pretty unusual to name generics with long names :) I'd go with `I`.

Comment: Sure, why not. Although I personally think that this is a bad habit, I like descriptive names. "It's pretty unusual" is the reason why old C programmers still use horrible short cut names with `m_` and `p` prefixes because "that's how it's always been done"

Comment: There is a reason to that, though: usually types have one, at most two generic parameters and their usage is obvious.

Comment: Not always, though, I had situations that required 4+ generics.

Comment: @Finomnis Thank you so much! In addition, if I wish to perform multiple implementations on the list of integers (eg. first Multiply, then Subtract), how should I go about doing this? By adding `Subtract::new(Box::new(iter), 2)` after implementing Multiply, the "value borrowed after move" error will occur.

Comment: @jessica14 The `value borrowed after move` does not come from the line you show here, it comes from the fact that you use `iter` later again. I would need to see your full code for that, please provide a link to https://play.rust-lang.org/ with the code that causes the error.

Comment: @jessica14 https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1c59c565930cb098eb0547abd58963be